# Contextual member has no associated value in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, uicolor

While translating code

```
$0.backgroundColor = .redColor()
```

Into Swift 3 I'm receiving this error:

> /Users//Documents/projects//MyCell.swift:52:35: Contextual member 'redColor' has no associated value

How can I translate this code manually?

Comment: "How can I translate this code?" – Look up the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor) (top Google hit for "UIColor").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 3 `.redColor()` is changed to just `.red`.

```
 $0.backgroundColor = .red
```

For more detail about this read [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor) on `UIColor` under `Symbols` section check `Type Properties`.